# PHP/WSO2: receiving an error: missing SOAP header with signing only option

Tags: php, wso2

I'm stuck on developing WSDL-client for my client. I'm newbie with PHP/WSO2, so please be patient with my gaps :)
What's the problem: client can connect to server, but receiving

```
wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/src/wsf_wsdl.c(1073) [wsf_wsdl]Fault payload is <soap:Faulxmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:InvalidSecurity</faultcode><faultstring>An error was discovered processing the &lt;wsse:Security&gt; header</faultstring></soap:Fault>
```

I can't change server configuration, and I can't get information on how server is configured (WSPolicy etc.).
WSDL service provider told me that the following properties are used on server side:
signing,
no crypto,
issuerSerial
and that's it. 
Again, the client can connect to server (certificates are correct), but the error appears on response.

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
        <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:InitiatorToken>
                <sp:RecipientToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:RecipientToken>
                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Basic256Rsa15/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                <sp:Layout>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Strict/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Layout>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
        <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss10>
        <sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
            <sp:Body/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
    </wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
```

And the some code from a client:

```
private function getWSPolicy() {
    $policyXML = file_get_contents("signp.xml");
    $policy = new WSPolicy(array("security"=>$policyXML));
    return $policy;
} 

private function getWSSecurityToken() {
    $clientPrivateKeyPath = 'ssl/key.pem';
    $clientCertificate = 'ssl/cert-only.pem';
    $serverPem = 'ssl/server.pem';

    $pvt_key = ws_get_key_from_file($clientPrivateKeyPath);
    $pvt_cert = ws_get_cert_from_file($clientCertificate);
    $rec_cert =  ws_get_cert_from_file($serverPem);

    $sec_token = new WSSecurityToken(array("privateKey" => $pvt_key,
                    "certificate" => $pvt_cert,
                                            "receiverCertificate" => $rec_cert
                                     ));
    return $sec_token;
}

public function getClient() {
    if ($this->webpay_client == null) {
    $serverPem = 'ssl/newcert.pem';
    $wsdl_xml = "service.wsdl";
        $this->webpay_client = new WSClient
                (
                    array ("wsdl" => $wsdl_xml,
                        "classmap" => $this->getClassMap(),
            "policy" => $this->getWSPolicy(),
                        "securityToken" => $this->getWSSecurityToken(),
            "HTTPMethod" => "post",
            "useSOAP" => 1.1,
            "CACert" => $serverPem,
                        )
                );
    }
    return $this->webpay_client;
}
```

Maybe someone could help/point me how to solve this issue? Or how to debug to set some other options? (Tcpdump shows message and mentioned resoponse).

Edit:
I found in wsf log that other policies in WSPolicy were sent to server:

```
wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/src/wsf_policy.c(221) [WSF/PHP] creating rampart client outgoing policy node 
     <wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"><wsp:ExactlyOne><wsp:All><sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702"><wsp:Policy><sp:InitiatorToken><wsp:Policy><sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient"><wsp:Policy><sp:WssX509V3Token10></sp:WssX509V3Token10></wsp:Policy></sp:X509Token></wsp:Policy></sp:InitiatorToken><sp:RecipientToken><wsp:Policy><sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never"><wsp:Policy><sp:WssX509V3Token10></sp:WssX509V3Token10></wsp:Policy></sp:X509Token></wsp:Policy></sp:RecipientToken><sp:AlgorithmSuite><wsp:Policy><sp:Basic256Rsa15></sp:Basic256Rsa15></wsp:Policy></sp:AlgorithmSuite><sp:Layout><wsp:Policy><sp:Strict></sp:Strict></wsp:Policy></sp:Layout></wsp:Policy></sp:AsymmetricBinding><sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702"><wsp:Policy><sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier></sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier><sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial></sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial><sp:MustSupportRefEmbeddedToken></sp:MustSupportRefEmbeddedToken></wsp:Policy></sp:Wss10></wsp:All></wsp:ExactlyOne></wsp:Policy>
```

Could this produce such error?

Comment: Tried to use tcpmon with no luck.Looks like tcpmon can't correctly forward https connections.